# Error: Could not find or load main class JDBCExample

Tags: java, postgresql, cmd

Hello I am trying to run a java file in cmd (Windows) with this:

C:\test>java -cp c:\test\postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc41.jar;c:\test JDBCExample

where postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc41.jar & JDBCExample are already in the folder "test".
and JDBCExample.java is:

---

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

     public class JDBCExample {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            System.out.println("-------- PostgreSQL "
                    + "JDBC Connection Testing ------------");

            try {

                Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

                System.out.println("Where is your PostgreSQL JDBC Driver? "
                        + "Include in your library path!");
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;

            }

            System.out.println("PostgreSQL JDBC Driver Registered!");

            Connection connection = null;

            try {

                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                        "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/testdb", "java_postgres",
                        "4scoreand7yearsago");

            } catch (SQLException e) {

                System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;

            }

            if (connection != null) {
                System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
            }
        }

        }
```

---

I have tried to run a simple "Hello World" java file in the same "test" folder yet it also says the same error.
And next, I also tried changing directory to a source folder of a .java file which I am REALLY SURE that it works perfect in Netbeans or Eclipse, (sorting algo and etc), yet still in the cmd it says the same error when compiling. :(

Any help? Also, I already added in the Path of my computer's Environment Variables a "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;" and added a new one named CLASSPATH where it points to a "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin" but to no avail, still the same error.

OR COULD ANY OF YOU JUST HELP ME FIND ANOTHER WAY OF SETTING UP THE JDBC DRIVE. THAT'S ALL THANK YOU. T_T

Comment: Where's the class file located?

Comment: Please post the full error message and the stack trace

Comment: In C:\test @DaveNewton.

Comment: Are you missing a backslash? should be: C:\test>java -cp c:\test\postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc41.jar;c:\test\JDBCExample

Comment: "Error: Could not find or load main class JDBCExample" that's it. @Barranka 
And what is stack trace if you may? I am an amateur programmer but I am still oblivious to some programming terms. Please enlighten me.

Comment: Catch an exception and print it's stack trace (something like `try { /* Some code goes here */} catch(Exception e){ System.err.println(e.getMessage()); e.printStackTrace(System.err); }`. Exception handling is one of the first things you whould learn. Please read: [Java Tutorials: Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html). Also, read [what a Stack trace is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace)

Comment: It says "Usage: java [-options] class [args. . .]  <to execute a class> or java [-options] -jar jarfile [args. . .] <to execute a jar file>"

I think it means that that was a syntax error or somewhat like that @Donal.

Comment: Umm, but the question is, why would A SIMPLE HELLO WORLD PROGRAM or A PROGRAM THAT WILL SURELY RUN ON A NETBEANS OR ECLIPSE wouldn't run in the cmd's java compiler? Does it mean that it's either my "execution syntax" of the file is wrong or I messed up something with the Path in the Environment Variables @Barranka? :/

Comment: @Barranka The program has to start running before any exceptions will be caught by the OP's code. And the OP's code already has exception handling in place.

Comment: It's an SO formatting issue with the backslash. If you're in "C:\", and `JDBCExample.class` is in `C:\test`, it should work.

Comment: The class path must point to the directory containing *the compiled .class files*, not the source .java files. When you use an IDE it will compile and set up the class path for you. Without an IDE you must either compile manually using `javac` or let the class path point to the location where your IDE has placed the .class files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad, it's only a matter of compilation and running problem.

```
/> javac JDBCExample.java
/> java JBDCExample
```

Sorry for the disturbance people! xD